# How to remove a line from a file containing certain pattern value in variable?

Tags: bash, file, sed

I have a file that contains names of directories and some other information, but the names always come first.The file looks like this:

```
/home/user/Desktop/IS/proj_1/sch/text 4 2018-03-14 07:41:01
/home/user/Desktop/IS/file1.txt 3 2018-03-14 16:50:01
...
```

I have a variable "name" that contains this for example:

```
/home/user/Desktop/IS/file1.txt
```

And I need to delete that one particular line from the file somehow. I've searched many posts and tried using various quotations and ways of expansions, but nothing did the trick. If I type it in directly, it deletes the line without problem, but I'm having a hard time doing it from a variable. This is what I came up with but it still doesn't work.

```
sed -i '/"$name"/d' $File_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
sed -i "\|$name|d" "$File_name"
```

As you can see, I changed the delimiter for `|`, you can pick another one depending of your needs from most of ascii characters (not all works)

Comment: Just a note that a filename may contain pipe character as well.

Comment: Not the case here. UP to OP to choose another valid ASCII char

Comment: It does get rid of that one - however, it writes the output to terminal and doesn't actually edit the file

Answer (score 2):

Whatever given in single quotes wont get expanded.

Try:

```
sed -i "/$name/d" $File_name
```

If you have problems with /, escape them properly.

```
name=$(echo "$name"|sed -e "s/\//\\\\\//g")
sed -i "/$name/d" $File_name
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed` command doesn't allow plain string based search and performs search using only a regex (BRE or ERE). That requires escaping all special regex meta-characters in search pattern.

Better to use a **non-regex approach using awk**:

```
name='/home/user/Desktop/IS/file1.txt'
awk -v p="$name" '!index($0, p)' file
```

```
/home/user/Desktop/IS/proj_1/sch/text 4 2018-03-14 07:41:01
```